# Several strange errors when building project using separate files C++

Tags: c++

I'm able to build and run a particular project in Visual Studio when all of the code is in one main .cpp file, but when I separate the file into a class (.cpp and .h) and main .cpp file, I get several weird errors.

Here is the code when it's in 3 separate files, and not working:

```
//main.cpp
#include "student.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    Student student;
    student.setStudentID("A1C");
    student.print();
}
```

```
//Student.h
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

class Student
{
public:
    Student();
    string getStudentID() const;
    void setStudentID(string studentID);
    void print();
private:
    string studentID;
};


#endif
```

```
//Student.cpp
#include "Student.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Student::Student() {
    this->studentID = "default";
}

string Student::getStudentID() const {  
    return this->studentID;
}

void Student::setStudentID(string studentID) {
    this->studentID = studentID;
}


void Student::print() {
    cout << "student ID: " << studentID << endl;
}
```

Here is the code when it's all in one main.cpp file, and working:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    Student();
    string getStudentID();  //const?
    void setStudentID(string studentID);
    void print();
private:
    string studentID;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    Student student;
    student.setStudentID("A1C");
    student.print();
}

Student::Student() {
    this->studentID = "default";
}

string Student::getStudentID() {  //const?
    return this->studentID;
}

void Student::setStudentID(string studentID) {
    this->studentID = studentID;
}


void Student::print() {
    cout << "student ID: " << studentID << endl;
}
```

[Here are some of the errors that I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WyyE.png)

Comment: Your `student.h` file is missing `#include <string>` and (your unfortunate usage of) `using namespace std`

Comment: @CoryKramer even if you don't want to use the full names, you should be able to do better than `using namespace std;`: `using std::string;`

Comment: Just added #include <string> and I still get the same errors.  I appreciate the tip on namespace std.  Why is that looked down upon?  I'm learning c++ and my learning material suggested it ...

Comment: It leads to many more potential name clashes with your own code, and (in particular) any library headers you might be using.  It seems to be quite common in learning texts, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSanders; that's really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In the file Student.h you are using `string`, but `string` is not (yet) known. Read the Include file from top to bottom. Nowhere in the file is there any hint as to what `string` is supposed to be.

`#include <string>` in your Student.h file will introduce `std::string` to the file. From here on, `std::string` will be valid. But that's still not enough, since you are using `string` and not `std::string` in your class.

Do *not* include a `using namespace std` in your header file. If you do so, you force this namespace on all your "customers" of the header file. If any other file includes your `Student.h` with the `using namespace` in it, they will also get the `using namespace...` statement, even if they do not want it. Headerfiles should be self contained and should not introduce stuff, others may not want.

Also do not add a `using std::string` in your header file. While not as bad as a `using namespace std` there may be (and later in your professional life *will* be) instances, where you have different kinds of `string`. Perhaps a `std::string` and an `oldfashioned::string` or `utf_something::string`.

For simplicity, just write `std::string studentId`. IOW, use the fully qualified name of `string` in your header file.

In .cpp files these rules are somewhat relaxed, since no other file will include your .cpp file.

---

Bonus:

- lookup #pragma once
- always include system headers *before* your own headers
- But beware of include order. Every header file should include all headers it needs, because ...
- ... the worst thing that can happen is that your code changes depending on the order in which you include headers. It should not matter. Including "Student.h" should introduce the Student class and nothing else.

---

Bonus++

- take your time to learn about the C(++) preprocessor. #include is not really a C++ language statement like `class`, `for` etc... It is just a directive for the compiler to read the included file first.
- Your compiler will have a switch (such as /P with Microsoft Visual C++) which will not compile the code but produce the actual included files and store the in a *.p (or something) file. It will let you see what the preprocessor does with your code before it is passed on to the compiler. It's an interesting and teaching experience. Try it. Don't be put off by the seemingly complex file. Search for "class Student" in that file and take it from there.

Comment: That fixed it!  Thank you!   I'll be looking into all of those things and noting the best practices you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

change student.h to this

```
//Student.h
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <string>
class Student
{
public:
    Student();
    std::string getStudentID() const;
    void setStudentID(std::string studentID);
    void print();
private:
    std::string studentID;
};


#endif
```

and it compiles and runs fine

BTW.

dont do this

```
void Student::setStudentID(string studentID) {
    this->studentID = studentID;
}
```

have a naming convention for fields in a class so they are distinct

ie

```
//Student.h
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <string>
class Student
{
public:
    Student();
    std::string getStudentID() const;
    void setStudentID(std::string studentID);
    void print();
private:
    std::string studentID_; <<<<========
};
```

then

```
void Student::setStudentID(string studentID) {
    studentID_ = studentID;
}
```

why, because

First its the accepted way in c++ world (the naming standard might differ, m_ prefix is common too)

second you might write this

```
void Student::setStudentID(string studentID) {
    studentID = studentID;
}
```

which will compile but is maybe not what you mean. Of course here its obvious but in denser code, not so much

Comment: Changing the "string" to "std::string" and adding #include <string> fixed most of the errors. I still get 2 weird errors (see below). I'm not understanding either, because the function that they apply to isn't declared as a static member and it's not overloaded. Error C2511 'std::string Student::getStudentID(void)': overloaded member function not found in 'Student' Error C2671 'Student::getStudentID': static member functions do not have 'this' pointers

Comment: @Mike, that error does nt exist in you posted code (I ran your posted code clean) so please update the question with your new code

Comment: omg ... it went away when I recompiled ... Thank you for your help; I really appreciate it!